# Plane intersecting sphere

Tags: asymptote, pst-solides3d

[image: Plane intersecting a sphere]

I have made this in matematica, but I need similar picture in metapost. Any ideas how to do so?

```
    sl3d1 = Graphics3D[{{Opacity[.5], 
            Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1]}, {PointSize[.02], 
            Point[{{1, 0, 0}}]}, {PointSize[.02], Point[{{0, 1, 0}}]}, 
            Opacity[.5], Red, 
            Polygon[{{-1, -1, 0}, {-1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, -1, 0}}]}]

    sl3d2 = ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[t], Sin[t], 0}, {t, -0, 2*Pi}, 
            PlotStyle -> {Black, Dashing[{.01, .01}]}] 

    Show[{sl3d1, sl3d2}, Boxed -> False]
```

Comment: Hi! And what is your Mathematica code for this sphere?

Comment: Welcome! Why do you need it in Metapost? And why have you tagged it `pst-solides3d`? Does Metapost even do 3D? (Not saying it doesn't - I've just only ever seen it used for 2D.)

Comment: @cfr Sure you can do [3D in Metapost](http://www-math.univ-poitiers.fr/~phan/m3Dplain.html) but Asymptote is much more capable.

Comment: sl3d1 = Graphics3D[{{Opacity[.5], 
    Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1]}, {PointSize[.02], 
    Point[{{1, 0, 0}}]}, {PointSize[.02], Point[{{0, 1, 0}}]}, 
   Opacity[.5], Red, 
   Polygon[{{-1, -1, 0}, {-1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, -1, 0}}]}]                 sl3d2 = ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[t], Sin[t], 0}, {t, -0, 2*Pi}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Black, Dashing[{.01, .01}]}]                                Show[{sl3d1, sl3d2}, Boxed -> False]

Comment: Im wiriting a paper and I have made all of my pics in matematica, but my mentor insists on metapost(or whatever similar in latex if its not possible to do in metapost). I have menaged to do 2D graphics, but I have problems with this one.  Thank You!

Comment: @Una, this post will require very heavy editing. Please break up your Mathematica code into small pieces so that people can see the different conceptual parts. Format your code appropriately. Make a basic attempt by drawing a sphere with TeX, which will serve as your [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: @Thruston That's a significant extension, right? Like `tikz-3dplot` does 3D in 2D, so to speak?

Comment: @cfr yes, that's right, there's no 3D support in the basic MP language.  Anthony Phan's library is one of several attempts at 3D in MP,  afaik they all suffer from a lack of maintenance.